# How to scroll vertically aside div if higher than main block in responsive layout?

Tags: css, responsive-design, height

I got two divs, in one row, side by side. 
The second one is the main one, more important.
I want the row to not to be higher than main one.
So when content of first div makes it too high, overflowed content should be hidden or scrolled.
Look at the code below.
How to make it with css?

Important: my layout is responsive, so I'm looking for a solution without fixed height.

```css
<style>
.wrap {border: 5px solid green}
.aside {display: inline-block; width: 25%; font-size: 300%; vertical-align: top; background-color: yellow; }
.main {display: inline-block; width: 75%; font-size: 300%; background-color: red; padding-bottom: 56%; vertical-align: top}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="aside">
  I want this block to be scrolled vertically if height is greater than Main Block's height.<br>
  The height of "wrap" block should be the same like Main Block's height.
  <Br><br>
    long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
  </div><div class="main"> Main Block </div>
</div>
```

Comment: most likely you will not to have some javascript/jquery to do this, this may not be done with css only...probably you can tag this question under javascript for quick responses.

Comment: well, it's easy with javascript, I'm looking for pure css solutiion

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some JavaScript for a optimal result. But you can try the following code without JavaScript:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="aside">
  I want this block to be scrolled vertically if height is greater than Main Block's height.<br>
  The height of "wrap" block should be the same like Main Block's height.
  <Br><br>
    long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
  </div><div class="main"> Main Block </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
  border: 5px solid green
}

.aside {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 300%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: scroll;

}

.main {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75%;
  font-size: 300%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
```